# Prove that centroid, orthocenter and circumcenter are collinear

Tags: geometry

Prove that centroid, orthocenter and circumcenter are in the ratio 2:1.!!

my  attempt..

I could prove they are in the ratio 2:1.Assuming that they are collinear.But couldn't prove that they are collinear.I need help?

Comment: There is a proof on Khan Academy of this I believe.

Comment: can u provide the link?

Comment: How could you do what you said without knowing they're collinear? I recommend a proof (of both, simultaneously) using vector algebra.

Comment: See [Euler line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_line).

Comment: While the vector algebra proof is neat, how do I prove that the collinear, using elementary pure geometry? I understand that the medial triangle is a medial triangle is a scaled down(similar) version of the original triangle by a factor of 1/2. They share medians and therefore the centroid. I also know, that the orthocenter H of the medial triangle is the circumcenter K of the original triangle.

Answer (score 2):

The circumcenter $O$ of $ABC$ is just the orthocenter of the medial triangle $A'B'C'$, which, obviously, shares its centroid $G$ with $ABC$. Since $\frac{AG}{GA'}=\frac{BG}{GB'}=\frac{CG}{GC'}=2$, $G,O,H$ are collinear and $\frac{HG}{GO}=2$ holds.

Comment: $A' B' C'$ is related to $A B C$ by a reflection through the point G followed by a 2:1 dilation from G.This operation leaves G fixed and moves H' (which is O) to H. The line $ O G H$  is called the Euler line of the triangle.